# Error message when I log in about ayuwuwuqec.dll

Tags: windows-7, dll

Any idea what this is?

It appears when I log in (Windows 7 Home Premium, 64 bit).
So far I have scanned my PC for viruses, trojans etc and re-installed Chrome.

[image: Error Message]

**UPDATE**: I found this is the registry at this location: 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER / Software / Microsoft / Windows / CurrentVersion / Xqovaniya

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your anti-virus tools deleted the actual virus (ayuwuwuqec.dll), but not the registry entry that directs Windows to automatically start it.

Delete that registry entry (Xqovaniya) and that message should go away.  The registry entry is safe to delete.  (Touch anything else in the registry at your own risk, of course.)

Comment: That fixed it -- no more error messages when I log in. Thanks!